# Is there any option in QGIS to draw parallel lines that snap on the outside part of the line (adjacent lines) that are independent from scale?

Tags: qgis, snapping, rendering, parallel-lines, map-unit

I have to draw a map of a public bus transport network and i have a problem in the avenues where a lot of lines passes by.
My objective is to make a visual map where the lines in those avenues are parallel one from the other and with no space between them, in order to see all of them at the same time, regardless the scale.

I've tried snapping options, and parallel drawing (CAD tools), but the issue is that when i change the scale, the distance between lines change and they collide or separate one from the other, messing everything.

So my question is:

- Is there any option to draw adjacent lines that stays adjacent independently of the scale of visualisation?

Note: I don't know if adjacent is used for what I mean, so here I copy an example of what I'm searching for:
[image: Objective]

---

This is what happens when I zoom in:

[image: Zoom in]

And when I zoom out:

[image: Zoom out]

EDIT: Here I share a situation of why the suggested solution wouldn't work for me. Three lines share the same street for a while, but then they separate into three different streets.

[image: Split]

I can't use a single line with several symbolisation because all along the network, the lines split and join again (there are more than 15 bus lines).

The data contained in the attribute data doesn't help me, because it's only a layer full of lines, with no attribute other than some network information (number of buses/hour, passenger/hour, etc.).
(QGIS 2.8.6 working on Windows 7)

Comment: In QGIS 2.16, new [rendering simplication](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-new-options-for-on-the-fly-simplification) options were introduced. Although I can't confirm if this will help in your situation.

Comment: The way that I would do this in ArcGIS for Desktop is by [setting a reference scale on the data frame](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-data-frame-reference-scales.htm).

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo, the problem with this solution (that can be implemented in QGIS, changing the units to "map unit") is that I need the lines to change their width depending on the scale but not the relation between them. I know that what I need is something very specific and difficult to implement. Something more appropriate for Illustrator than for a GIS software.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do all the line shapefiles lie on top of one another or is there already some sort of offset between then?

Comment: In some cases they lie on top of one another and in other cases they don't. What do you propose?

Comment: I am only superficially familiar with QGIS but I think your `changing the units to "map unit"` is very different to setting a reference scale.

Comment: Could you share a small set of example data?

Comment: I'll try to give you some data to try to solve this problem. It may be impossible though. Anyway, i've given you the 50 points bounty, because of your effort (i had to give it or it would be lost).

Comment: Thank you but would love some sample data to work on this more!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure this is what you are really after, but you can use a **single line** with a different symbolisation to create the appearance of two parallel lines.

Starting with a 1.1 km line in CRS 3857 (metric, pseudo-Mercator as per Google and other web services):

[image]

In properties, add another symbol layer (so you see two lines).

[image]

Set the width of each line in **map units** - in this case, the units are metres and I've selected a width of 50 metres, and set the **offset** of each line to half their width, with one of them having an equal but **negative** offset:

[image]

This gives the appearance you're after:

[image]

... and it persists at different scales:

[image]

Comment: I thought about this but that would be difficult to deal with at separations of lines.

Comment: @Victor about separation: you can create different attributes like "single line", "double line" with value True/False and use rule-based labelling.

Comment: @Victor agreed, need to get more info from OP about the nature of the data; this solution may not work depending on how lines connect and separate.

Comment: @Andreu, perhaps you can click 'edit' on your original post, and add that information (and an example of where this solution __wouldn't work__), and (better yet) some sample data?

Comment: @Simbamangu First of all, thanks for trying a solution and sharing it with me.
Even if that solution can work in some cases, as Victor said, it would be difficult to use it when lines separate from the others. In fact, that happens everytime the lines split into different streets.

The data works like that: I have all the lines of the Bus network in different shapefiles. The "problem" is that all of them are reallistically plotted, so when I choose more than one at a time, they collide. So my objective is to make a map where you can visually see the whole network.
I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

If by "snapping option" you mean that you cannot change the geometry of the polylines and you can only change their symbology, then what you described is almost impossible.

From your examples, you seem to be looking to render polylines such that the parallel portions touch each other without overlapping, e.g. by having the boundary between the two parallel lines equally divide their separation distance. If we view the polyline representations as their **buffers**, then you can come up with cases (similar to your Fig. 4), where the same line should have different "buffer" widths at different portions (dictated by the closest neighboring lines). *In other words, your buffer width would depend on other polylines and can vary at different segments of the polylines. But typically, symbolization only uses information/attributes of the feature itself.*

Of course, you can always use a fixed radius "buffer" around the lines, and **manually manipulate** the vertices (or edit the buffers) so that the boundaries snap to each other . Then the buffers would remain "snapped" with zoom in/out, although this is a lot of manual labor and adjustment may be required if new lines are added.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can change the geometry of the polylines, but since there are a lot of lines crossing each other and a lot of different combinations, it becomes very time-consuming and tedious. I've tried the buffer solution, but it is even harder than just editing lines shape, because if have to define dependant visualisation in all the segments of all the lines.

Comment: @AndreuAmoros. This is exactly what I was suggesting. Editing the lines (or the associated "buffers") is indeed time consuming, but it is needed by the nature of your requirement that these buffers snap to each other.